# Why does save_kable to PDF result in bad quality PDFs?

Tags: kable, kableextra

Why does `save_kable` command of the `kableExtra` package results in bad resolution PDF? I have observed that when a PDF is rendered with `magick`(which is standard in `kableExtra`) the quality is pretty bad (see screenshot below). When `magick` is not installed, it works, but with another renderer (Qt5.5.1 in my case; Macbook Pro 2018, OSX 10.14.6; imagemagick@6 is installed vie brew). However, uninstalling R's `magick`, rebooting etc. works but is not convenient (especially if you need magick also for other R packages like `summarytools`) and therefore does not turn out to be a permanent solution. I might handle something not in the way it was intended and I am happy to get some help on this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've had the same problem with magick on windows: I installed ghostscript because I was getting "Error in magick_image_readpath(path, density, depth, strip, defines)" and searching seemd to suggest that not having ghostscript was the issue. After installing ghostscript save_kable seemed to be rendering the pdf as an image, where before it was using some vector graphics method. The image is not just inferior in quality: I also cannot highlight and therefore copy text for pasting, and the file size is about 50x larger. Ideally there'd be an option to use vector graphics where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I found a solution which looks pretty standard. Simply include `density` in the `save_kable` function. This would have save me a lot of time.

```
 p <- kable(yourdata, escape = F) %>% 
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed"), full_width = F)
 p %>% save_kable("yourdata.pdf", density = 300)
```