# Poor resolution and blurry texts when using knitr to create a PDF file in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

**EDIT**: Never mind! It seems like the PREVIEW generated by RSTUDIO is blurry. The actual PDF looks fine!

I'm using knitr package to create a PDF report in rmarkdown. I'm using kableExtra package to embed a table. However, the resolution of the said table is poor and the contents are blurry.

Did anyone else have this problem? I looked at increasing the DPI, but it seems like that's only for plots and not tables.

This is my example Rmarkdown file:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document: 
     latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
\```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

mtcars[1:6] %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "") %>%
  kable_styling(
    full_width=TRUE, 
    bootstrap_options = c("striped"),
  )
\```
````

Answer (score 0):

Besides Rmarkdown, I certainly had problems with blurry PDF's in R `knitr`/`kable`. My solution was easy (but hard to find though). During saving procedure with `save_kable`, include the desired resolution with the command `density`.
For example: `save_kable("yourdata.pdf", density = 300)`. See also here: [Why does save_kable to PDF result in bad quality PDFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022918/why-does-save-kable-to-pdf-result-in-bad-quality-pdfs)